# Pull values from one column that match with 2 separate values in another column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Let me share an example:

```
Col1 Col2
123  A
456  B
234  A
456  A
098  A
567  B
567  A
```

I need a postgresSQL query which returns something like

- Result

```
456
567
```

both values 456, 567 from Col1 match with values A and B from Col2.

Comment: select col1 from table where col2 = 'B';  ????

Answer (score 1):

Group by `Col1` and count the distinct `Col2` values. Get only these with count = 2.

```sql
select col1 from the_table
where col2 in ('A','B')
group by col1 
having count(distinct col2) = 2;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/as9aFUoEjGf6twUbcxQ6XG/0)